# Error in shapefile$shp : $ operator is invalid for atomic vectors- DSsim package R

Tags: r

I am trying to add a shapefile, when making a region for the DSsim package in R. But I keep getting the error code- Error in shapefile$shp : $ operator is invalid for atomic vectors. Can anyone help me?

The code I have is as follows:

```
library(DSsim)
file.path("C:/Users/user/Desktop/Lorna/Distance/WITH VARIABLES/C3p", "C3p.shp")
C3P <- shapefiles::read.shp("C3p.shp")
region.label <- make.region(region.name = "C3P", strata.name = 0, units = "km", area = 51.02, shapefile=("C3p.shp"), check.LinkID = TRUE)
```

Answer (score 0):

The help for `make.region` says:

```
shapefile: a shapefile object of the region loaded into R using
          ‘read.shapefile(shape.name)’ from the shapefiles library.
```

but you have done:

```
region.label <- make.region(...., shapefile=("C3p.shp"), ....)
```

which is the name of the shapefile, in parentheses (these brackets).

Try using `read.shapefiles` instead of `read.shp`:

```
C3P <- shapefiles::read.shapefile(
    "C:/Users/user/Desktop/Lorna/Distance/WITH VARIABLES/C3p"
)
```

Assuming the path to your shapefile is `"C:/Users/user/Desktop/Lorna/Distance/WITH VARIABLES/C3p.shp"` and similarly for `C3p.shx` etc.

and then:

```
region.label <- make.region(
  region.name = "C3P",
  strata.name = 0,
  units = "km", 
  area = 51.02,
  shapefile=C3P, # the object you created two lines previous 
  check.LinkID = TRUE)
```

Comment: Thank you, for the help. I have just tried what you suggested and the following error has shown : Error in file(shp.name, "rb") : cannot open the connection
In addition: Warning message:
In file(shp.name, "rb") :
  cannot open file 'C3p.shp.shp': No such file or directory

Clearly I have made an error in making the file connection,(the file name is correct), so will have to find where I am going wrong

Comment: I don't understand why you have a `file.path` call in your code that does nothing. If that's where the shapefile is then you need to give the full path in the `read.shapefile` call, and it looks like you have to omit the `.shp` bit. See edits.